# postfix + dovecot + mariadb send and recive email directory is not the same

Tags: email, centos

everyone.
   I'm install postfix + dovecot email system , and configure store virtual email account & password with mariadb on centos 7.
   I followed this [course](https://www.linode.com/docs/email/postfix/email-with-postfix-dovecot-and-mysql-on-centos-7) step on step . Lucky， I succed to start mariadb & postfix & dovecot. 
   Then I telnet to pop3 and login & quit. I found some folders was created at '/home/vmail/$mydomain/$user/'.  However, I run 'telnet localhost smtp' and do :

```
mail from: sales@example.com
rcpt to: sales@example.com
data
This is a test email.
.
quit
```

I found it succed . But when I look the folder /home/vmail, I found there is some folders created '/home/vmail/vmail/Maildir' , and the new mail was send to this '/home/vmail/vmail/Maildir/new' folder. I can't find setting like 'virtual_mail_folder' in postfix configure file . 
  Where is wrong ? And how to fix it ? Every answer is helpful, thank you.